# Change value of a variable during script execution

Tags: matlab

I'm running a simulation which is controlled by Matlab. The Matlab enters a loop and controls the simulation sequentially. Is it possible to change the variable value(e.g.. a flag) by user input during loop execution so that I can control the behaviour of the simulation in real time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value based on some condition, then use can use the [`input`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) command.

Another option is to create a small `pushbutton` and then write its callback. In the callback function, you can write `input` command and request user input. Use the method which suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will try with the callback function since i need to break the loop on my command. I will try to find some more resources online.

Comment: To have an idea of how to write a GUI (its just a single button), see [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24861-41-complete-gui-examples) great resource. First 4-5 GUIs should help you a lot.

Comment: I will check it out. I have much experience with visual studio so i suppose it's similar. Thank you again. I appreciate your help.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. How can I add a GUI to the existing script. I can create a new GUI (FIG and M files).

Comment: I think one of those 41 GUIs have an example of what you want.